# Axios Error Response Using TypeScript, React and React-Query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

I need to display the error message and if it has no error message just default it to an error status code. Problem right now is that it says `Property 'message' does not exist on type 'MyErrorResponse'.`

[image]

**auth service**

```
import { AxiosError } from 'axios'
import { useMutation } from 'react-query'
import { _axios, URL_TEMPLATES } from '../api'

export type LoginPayload = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
};

type LoginResponse = {
  data: {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    token: string;
  };
};

type MyErrorResponse = {
  errors: { detail: string }[];
};

export const useLogin = () => {
  return useMutation<LoginResponse, AxiosError<MyErrorResponse>, LoginPayload>(
    (payload) => _axios.post(URL_TEMPLATES.LOGIN, { ...payload })
  )
}
```

**component**

```
const { mutate, error } = useLogin()

      {error && (
        <Typography variant='h6' sx={{ color: theme.palette.red, mt: 2 }}>
          {error.response?.data.message}
        </Typography>
      )}
```

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(error)` to see what's in it?

Comment: @Sheraff. Yes. just added an image above.

Comment: But then this `errors: { detail: string }[];` is wrong in your type definition, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyErrorResponse` should be typed according what you return from the backend. In this case, it should be,

```js
type MyErrorResponse = {
  message: string
};
```

the hint is from the error you got,  `Property 'message' does not exist on type 'MyErrorResponse'.` It's a typescript error that indicates you have invalid type.